# How does 'static' cling work

Tags: electrostatics, adhesion

I noticed that static cling film does not seem to electromagnetically interact with itself, from which I deduced that it cannot have a static charge.

Googling lead me to sites like [this one](https://www.signs.com/blog/static-clings-work-signage-101/), where it validates my own observations.  However, the site only mentions this by way of explanation:

> The static clings actually work due to the fact that the thin vinyl
>   they are made from act like a mini-suction cup when pressed onto a
>   similar cohesive force or surface.

And so he infers that the cling works via atmospheric differentials.  This doesn't seem right to me though.

What is the physics behind static clings?

Comment: van der Waals forces, I'll bet! The atmospheric consideration is probably a red herring, though squishing any air out will help the van der Waals forces do their thing across the whole surface.